# Bootstrap Datepicker - dropdown not... dropping

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm a complete newbie and have been struggling to successfully implement the [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker).

All I get is the input field with the "12-02-2013" value; there is no dropdown once I click on the field. I have looked at other examples here on stackoverflow and elsewhere but I haven't found an answer yet.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Datepicker</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2013" readonly><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>   

    <script>
        $('#dp3').datepicker();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the order of script, **`bootstrap.js` should be after `jQuery.js library`**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap- combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js"></script>
```

Also if you want the **`datepicker`** for `textbox`, then

remove the id from div and add it to input tag

```
<div class="input-append date"  data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" id="dp3" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2013" readonly><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

```js
$('#dp3').datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div class="input-append date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" id="dp3" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2013" readonly><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed `bootstrap.min.js` between jquery and `bootstrap-datepicker.js`. By the way, didn't the .min version already bundles all plugins at once? Seems OP is calling datepicker twice.  (ps.: I didn't downvoted)

Comment: @RaphaelDDL nice catch, but it is not needed if OP is working only for datepicker.  Anyway thanks.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I'm such a newbie that I had no idea that the order in which you called the scripts mattered. Thanks @user1671639

Comment: @monyobi Glad to help you :) FYI: whenever you go for a jQuery plugin remember to place the jQuery libray at top.

Comment: Although I kept the "dp3" id in the div, because otherwise the dropdown only appears when you click on the text field, but not on the appended icon.

Comment: Good to know about script order. I'm amazed at the response time. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1671639 I know min isn't needed if only datepicker, I was just saying because on OP's HTML code has both `min` and the `-datepicker` js' :P

Comment: I can' access the CSS and JS Files. It says Forbidden.

Comment: @Praveen : Great Job !!